# Custom 'image attribute in Ada?

Tags: syntax, attributes, ada

So I have a thing.

```
type Thing is new record
  ...elements...
end record;
```

I have a function which stringifies it.

```
function ToString(t: Thing) returns string;
```

I would like to be able to tell Ada to use this function for `Thing'image`, so that users of my library don't have to think about whether they're using a builtin type or a Thing.

However, the obvious syntax:

```
for Thing'image use ToString;
```

...doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

I don’t know why the language doesn’t support this, and I don’t know whether anyone has ever raised a formal proposal that it should (an Ada Issue or AI). The somewhat-related [AI12-0020](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ai12s/ai12-0020-1.txt?rev=1.2) (the 20th AI for Ada 2012) includes the remark "I don't think we rejected it for technical reasons as much as importance”.

You can see why the Ada Rapporteur Group might think this was relatively unimportant: you can always declare an `Image` function; the difference between

```
Pkg.Image (V);
```

and

```
Pkg.Typ’Image (V);
```

isn’t very large.

Comment: That's a shame. It's an annoying inconsistency in what's otherwise an admirably consistent language --- user-defined types ought not to be second-class constructs in a decent programming language. (Plus, my program is tied to GNAT, so being able to do `V'img` would be really useful.)

Comment: I tend to use generic packages to create a signature [type + image-function] and then access the Image function that way. (This allows for different to_string functions to be called depending on the instantiation; i.e. a debugging_string function or a simple to_string function.)

Comment: In fact, what I've ended up doing is to overload `&` so that I can seamlessly append my objects to strings. As I mostly want to do this when building messages to the user this suffices for most of my purposes. It's not a real solution, though.

Answer (score 3):

Ada 2022 now supports the **Image** attribute for all types. It does a fairly good job in most cases and can be redefined. It is only supported, however, by the following compiler versions:

- GCC 12, 13, 14 (using Text_Buffers)
- GNAT Community Edition 2021 (using Text_Buffers)
- GNAT Community Edition 2020 (using Text_Output.Utils)
- GCC 11 (using Text_Output.Utils)

To redefine the Image attribute for your type, you add the **Put_Image** aspect with a reference to your custom Image procedure. The first argument is the **Root_Buffer_Type'Class** text buffer, and depending on your GNAT version, it's either defined in **Text_Buffers**, or **Text_Output.Utils**. Since this feature is only supported in Ada 2022 and higher, an **Ada_2022** pragma, or build flag may also be required.

```
pragma Ada_2022;

with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Text_Buffers;

procedure Main is

   type Source_Location is record
      Line   : Positive;
      Column : Positive;
   end record
     with Put_Image => My_Put_Image;

   procedure My_Put_Image
     (Output : in out Ada.Strings.Text_Buffers.Root_Buffer_Type'Class;
      Value  : Source_Location);

   procedure My_Put_Image
     (Output : in out Ada.Strings.Text_Buffers.Root_Buffer_Type'Class;
      Value  : Source_Location)
   is
      Line   : constant String := Value.Line'Image;
      Column : constant String := Value.Column'Image;
      Result : constant String :=
        Line (2 .. Line'Last) & ':' & Column (2 .. Column'Last);
   begin
       Output.Put (Result);
   end My_Put_Image;

   Line_10 : constant Source_Location := (Line => 10, Column => 1);

begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Line_10'Image);
end Main;
```

It's unclear whether you can directly redefine **Image** for types defined externally or in the Ada Standard Library. However, **Image** can be redefined for their sub-types and derived types:

```
type Special_Interest is new Integer with Put_Image => Special_Interest_Image;
```

Answer (score 1):

One common method is to create a unary + function...

```
    function "+"(item : myType) return String;
```

which is syntactically very light.
Obvious disclaimer: may lead to some ambiguity when applied to numeric types (e.g. Put (+4);)

However there is still the distinction between prebuilt types and user defined types.
'img wouldn't be able to be used by your client's code though, unless you specified an interface that enforced this function to be present (what if the client called on 'img for a private type that didn't have a 'img function defined?).

If you end up having to have an interface, it really doesn't matter what the function is called.