# Convert type to string

Tags: types, ada

I created a type :

```
packages MyTypes.Type_A is
    subtype Counter_Type is Integer range 0 .. 15;
    type Array_Counter_Type is record
        Counter_01 : Counter_Type ;
        Counter_02 : Counter_Type ;
        Counter_03 : Counter_Type ;
        Counter_04 : Counter_Type ;
    end record;
end MyTypes.Type_A;
```

I want to display my array like this

```
MyArray : Array_Counter_Type;
print ( MyTypes.Type_A.Array_Counter_Type'Image (MyArray));
```

But I have error :

> prefix og "Image" attribute must be scalar type

How can I do ? And is it possible to "customize" the `Image` to concat the 4 counters splited with '-' ?

Comment: In order to customize the 'Image attribute, you'll have to write a function that takes a value of the type and returns a string. You'll probably call this function Image. I don't see why it's a problem to write Mytypes.Type_A.Image (Myarray) rather than what you tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s not possible yet, but it will be in Ada 202x [[AI12-0020-1](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ai12s/ai12-0020-1.txt?rev=1.20&raw=N)]. Until then you will have to define a subprogram (e.g `Image`) and call it explicitly. See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23982388) on SO.

Example using `GNAT.Formatted_String`:

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with GNAT.Formatted_String;

procedure Main is

   subtype Counter_Type is Integer range 0 .. 15;

   type Array_Counter_Type is
      record
         Counter_01 : Counter_Type;
         Counter_02 : Counter_Type;
         Counter_03 : Counter_Type;
         Counter_04 : Counter_Type;
      end record;

   -----------
   -- Image --
   -----------

   function Image (Array_Counter : Array_Counter_Type) return String is      
      use GNAT.Formatted_String;      
      Format : constant Formatted_String := +"%02d-%02d-%02d-%02d";
   begin      
      return
        -(Format
          & Array_Counter.Counter_01
          & Array_Counter.Counter_02
          & Array_Counter.Counter_03
          & Array_Counter.Counter_04);
   end Image;     

   AC : Array_Counter_Type := (0, 5, 10, 15);

begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Image (AC));
end Main;
```

But you could also use `Ada.Integer_Text_IO`, `Counter_Type'Image`, etc. instead if `GNAT.Formatted_String` is not available.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. But I don't understand the `+"..."` and the `-(...)`, (I'm new to Ada).

Comment: Ada allows operators (including the unary operators `+` and `-`) to be overloaded. Operators have strong mathematical semantics. Ada, however (as most languages), does not enforce these semantics. You are free to give the operator any (type dependent) behavior/semantics you like. Hence, you can (mis?)use the (overload) feature to define a function that has a very short (easy to write) and distinct "name". In the example, the operators act as functions that perform (type) transformations (see  [g-forstr.ads](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/ada/libgnat/g-forstr.ads?view=markup#l158)).