# Ada customise Image

Tags: string, image, ada

There is my type :

```
type T_MyType is (test1,
                  test2,
                  test3)
```

I want to customise `T_MyType'Image (..)` to display something like this

```
-- !!! Not working code !!!
when test1 => "String1";
when test2 => "String2";
when test3 => "Other String"; -- Not the same length
```

How can I do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom 'image attribute in Ada?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982388/custom-image-attribute-in-ada)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually define an Image function, without relying on new Ada 2022 features:

```
function Image (Item : T_MyType) return String
is begin
   case Item is
   when test1 => return "String1";
   when test2 => return "String2";
   when test3 => return "Other String";
   end case;
end Image;
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be possible if your compiler supports the [draft Ada 2022 standard ARM 4.10](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/2xrm/html/RM-4-10.html); GNAT CE 2021 does, and FSF GCC 11.1.0 doesn’t.

For type `T` you need to create a procedure with the spec

```ada
procedure Put_Image
   (Buffer : in out 
      Ada.Strings.Text_Buffers.Root_Buffer_Type'Class;
    Arg   : in T);
```

See [A4.12](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/2xrm/html/RM-A-4-12.html), Universal Text Buffers; and compile with the switch `-gnat2020`.

For example (and accepting, reluctantly, your redundant type name),

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Text_Buffers;

procedure Imaging is

   type T_MyType is (Test1,
                     Test2,
                     Test3);
   
   --  We have to see the procedure's spec ...
   procedure My_Image
     (Buffer : in out Ada.Strings.Text_Buffers.Root_Buffer_Type'Class;
      Arg    : in     T_MyType);

   --  ... so as to use it as a representation item ...
   for T_MyType'Put_Image use My_Image;
   
   --  ... before the compiler sees the body
   procedure My_Image
     (Buffer : in out Ada.Strings.Text_Buffers.Root_Buffer_Type'Class;
      Arg    : in     T_MyType)
   is
   begin
      Buffer.Put (case Arg is
                     when Test1 => "String1",
                     when Test2 => "String2",
                     when Test3 => "Other String");
   end My_Image;

begin
   for V in T_MyType loop
      Put_Line (V'Image);
   end loop;
end Imaging;
```

Comment: Does lang-ada syntax highlighting work now? Maybe it is time to ask to make that the default for source text for posts in the ada tag.

Comment: These code sections were introduced by 3 backticks, space, lang-ada. Works much better than the old version (attributes such as `’First` no longer interpreted as introducing strings). Not perfect; why are the `Buffer`s in the second code section highlighted as keywords? Not sure about changing the default, would end up with error messages etc being highlighted as Ada (we should be so lucky to get error messages ...)

Comment: Yes, maybe it's better to not set any default, although many other languages seem to be doing it. I've just suggested a change to the tag info for recommending use of this highlighting, so at least it's documented.